# When creating graph edge from 2 dimension array, what does arr[i][0], arr[i][1] mean?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, graph

Supposed edge relations are provided

```
    edges[][] = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,1],[3,2]]
```

when trying to create node relation, for example

```
    List[] list = new ArrayList[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        list [edges[i][1]].add(edges[i][0]);
    }
```

What does edges[i][1] and edges[i][0] mean here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to understand when you chop it up into variables, like this:

```
List[] list = new ArrayList[10];
for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
    int i1 = edges[i][1];
    int i0 = edges[i][0];
    list[i1].add(i0);
}
```

Alright lets go line by line:

1. **`List[] list = new ArrayList[10];`** – creates new list with size of 10
2. **`for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; i++)`** – executes `edges.length` times
3. **`int i1 = edges[i][1];`** – creates `int` referring to `edges[i][1]`(the *second* value of the `i`ᵗʰ member of edges)
4. **`int i0 = edges[i][0];`** – creates `int` referring to `edges[i][0]`(the *first* value of the `i`ᵗʰ member of edges)
5. **`list[i1].add(i0);`** – adds the **first value** of the **`i`ᵗʰ member** of `edges` to the place `i1` in `list`(That's a mouthful, read it very carefully).
6. **`}`** – ends for loop

Answer (score 2):

edges[i][1] - means for each i-th element get 2nd item in the edges array;
edges[i][0] - means for each i-th element get 1st item in the edges array;

Comment: No, it will. You have a loop in which you are iterating through all the items in the array, including last one [3,2].

Answer (score 1):

please find below representation of the logic

```
Row No.      |   Column No                   1             |          2

      1      |   1,list of edges{}                 <-------| list of edges(row 1 column 1) & data 0 |

      2      |   2,list of edges{}                 <-------| list of edges(row 2 column 1) & data 0 |

      3      |   3,list of edges{}                 <-------| list of edges(row 3 column 1) & data 1 |

      4      |   3,list of edges{}                 <-------| list of edges(row 4 column 1) & data 2 |
```